# Unsure about usage of async and callbacks in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, mocha.js

### Description:

I have a Mocha Test within my Node-App that should test whether a DB-Export of Mongo-DB-JSON-Documents is done correctly.
In my test I besides other tests also test if the download-directory is not empty.

### Expected result:

The test should await the downloads and only then check whether the directory is empty.

### Actual Result:

The test returns always green.

### My Question:

I understood that we have callbacks but promises are better.
I understood that async await is some syntactic sugar to promises.
And I understood that there is even RxJS (which I do not use here)

Somehow I have to deal with the callback from mogodb-backup.
See https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb-backup

I do not understand what I am doing wrong so that the tests always turn green (running in parallel to the download)

### mocha-test.js

```
describe('Database.downloadDocumentsOfType_KEYS()', function () {
  it('should result in data/exportFromCosmos/KEYS/admin/ag-data/ not being empty', function () {
    const config = {
      documents: ['DEFAULT', 'KEYS'],         
      exportpathDEFAULT: 'data/exportFromCosmos/DEFAULT/',
      exportpathKEYS: 'data/exportFromCosmos/KEYS/',
      uploadpath: 'data/uploadToAzureBlob/',
      crosscheckFile: 'data/crosscheckFile.txt'
    }

    async function f() {
      await Database.downloadDocumentsOfType_KEYS().then(expect(dir(config.exportpathKEYS + 'admin/ag-data/')).to.not.be.empty)
    }

    f()
  })
})
```

### Databasemodule-to-be-tested.js

```
const mongodbbackup = require('mongodb-backup')

const Database = {
  downloadDocumentsOfType_DEFAULT: () => {
  new Promise((resolve) => mongodbbackup({
    uri: process.env.DB_CONNECTION_STRING_READ,
    root: 'data/exportFromCosmos/DEFAULT',
    parser: 'json',
    callback: function(err) {
      if (err) {
        reject()
      } else {
        resolve()
      }
    }
  )}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
async function f() {
  await Database.downloadDocumentsOfType_KEYS().then(e)
}

f()
```

This fires off the asynchronous function immediately and

```
it('...', function (){})
```

finishes immediately.

So you need to use

```
describe('...',async function(){
  it('...',async function(){
   const f = async function(){
     await Database.downloadDocumentsOfType_KEYS();
     expect(dir(config.exportpathKEYS + 'admin/ag-data/')).to.not.be.empty);
   };
   await f();
  });
});
```

Also,

```
new Promise((resolve) => mongodbbackup({...
```

should be

```
new Promise((resolve,reject) => mongodbbackup({
```

Otherwise reject is `undefined`

Comment: your answer seems promissing...
Unfortunately the test and the backup itself seem still to run in parallel...

Comment: The test finishes .. then the documents appear in the folderstructure in my IDE

Comment: oh jeez I didn't read far enough of `await Database.downloadDocumentsOfType_KEYS().then(expect(dir(config.exportpathKEYS + 'admin/ag-data/')).to.not.be.empty)`

Comment: `downloadDocumentsOfType_KEYS` is not a `async func` / `promise` ?

Comment: Ah. Also never do `async function(){ return new Promise()}` --- `async function`s always return `Promise<type>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181162/discussion-between-marc-and-cody-g).